# Display vendor store-name (Dokan) on WooCommerce admin order preview

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, dokan

We add vendor information in the admin order details for each order via:

- [WooCommerce show vendor store-name (Dokan) in admin order details overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901474/woocommerce-show-vendor-store-name-dokan-in-admin-order-details-overview)

Now I also want to add this information also in the order preview. I found this answer

- [Display custom data on Woocommerce admin order preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845664/display-custom-data-on-woocommerce-admin-order-preview/53846801#53846801)

We change the hook to `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end` but now when we want to open the preview nothing happend.

Do we have to adjust the whole code in order that it works for the order preview or why is our approach not working?

```php
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_vendor_data( $order ) {
    // Empty array
    $shop_names = array();

    // Output
    echo '<strong>' . __( 'Vendor(s): ', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>';
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Author id
        $author_id = $product->post->post_author;
        
        // Shopname
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id );
        $shop_name = $vendor->get_shop_name();
        
        // OR JUST USE THIS FOR SHOPNAME
        // Shop name
        // $shop_name = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id )->get_shop_name();
        
        // NOT in array
        if ( ! in_array( $shop_name, $shop_names ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $shop_names[] = $shop_name;

            // Output
            echo $shop_name . ', ';
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_vendor_data', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in the link you referred to (By [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)). You can't get the `order` object as it's a template that loads specific data via Ajax and there is no arguments for `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start` action hook

Instead the filter hook `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_get_order_details` will allow you first to add some custom data that you will be able to call and display it via `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start` or `woocommerce_admin_order_preview_end` action hook

So you get:

```php
// Add custom order meta data to make it accessible in order preview template
function filter_woocommerce_admin_order_preview_get_order_details( $data, $order ) {
    // Empty array
    $shop_names = array();
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Author id
        $author_id = $product->post->post_author;
        
        // Shopname
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id );
        $shop_name = $vendor->get_shop_name();
        
        // OR JUST USE THIS FOR SHOPNAME
        // Shop name
        // $shop_name = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id )->get_shop_name();
        
        // NOT in array
        if ( ! in_array( $shop_name, $shop_names ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $shop_names[] = $shop_name;
        }
    }
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $shop_names ) ) {
        // Store the value in the data array
        $data['shop_names'] = implode( '<br>', $shop_names );
    }

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_get_order_details', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_order_preview_get_order_details', 10, 2 );

// Display custom values in order preview
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start() {
    // Output
    echo '<div class="wc-order-preview-wrapper">';
    echo '<div class="wc-order-preview-shop-names" style="padding:1.5em 1.5em 0; box-sizing:border-box;">';
    
    // H2
    echo '<h2>' . __( 'Vendor(s)', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h2>';
    
    // Call the stored value and display it
    echo '{{{ data.shop_names }}}';
    
    // Close
    echo '</div></div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_preview_start', 10, 0 );
```