# Woocommerce Show vendor Details such as Vendor Name, Store Name, Contact Details and Vendor Address (Dokan) in admin order details page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, dokan

We want to show the Store Name, Vendor name and Vendor Contact Details from an order admin order details page.

I'm using [WooCommerce show vendor store-name (Dokan) in admin order details overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902115/11987538) answer code to display the Store name for each product in the invoice.

Now we want to display Vendor Name and Vendor Contact details.

[Order Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P74yR.png)

My attempt:

```
// Adding Vendor Details admin shop_order pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 10, 1 );
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address( $order ) {
    // Empty array
    $shop_names = array();

    // Output
    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Store Name: ', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Author id
        $author_id = $product->post->post_author;
        
        // Shopname
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id );
        $shop_name = $vendor->get_shop_name();
        
        // OR JUST USE THIS FOR SHOPNAME
        // Shop name
        // $shop_name = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id )->get_shop_name();
        
        // NOT in array
        if ( ! in_array( $shop_name, $shop_names ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $shop_names[] = $shop_name;

            // Output
            echo '<p>' . $shop_name . '</p>';
        }
        
    }
    
        // Empty array
    $store_phones = array();
    
        // Output
    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Seller Contact: ', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Author id
        $author_id = $product->post->post_author;
        
        // Shopname
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id );
        
        $store_phone = $vendor->get_phone();
        
        // OR JUST USE THIS FOR SHOPNAME
        // Shop name
        // $store_phone = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id )->get_store_phone();
        
        // NOT in array
        if ( ! in_array( $store_phone, $store_phones ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $store_phone[] = $store_phone;

            // Output
            echo '<p>' . $store_phone . '</p>';
        }
        
    }
}
```

BY using this code we got store name but we aren't able to get vendor name and vendor contact details.

Comment: **1)** If you are using existing code, please always cite the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902115/11987538), because it gives proper credit to the author. **2)** Why would you use 2 foreach loops (and slow things down) when you can do this ALL with 1 loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue in this code `$store_phone[] = $store_phone;` replace with this `$store_phones[] = $store_phone;`

```
// Adding Vendor Details admin shop_order pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 10, 1 );
function action_woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address( $order ) {
    // Empty array
    $shop_names = array();

    // Output
    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Store Name: ', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Author id
        $author_id = $product->post->post_author;
        
        // Shopname
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id );
        $shop_name = $vendor->get_shop_name();
        
        // OR JUST USE THIS FOR SHOPNAME
        // Shop name
        // $shop_name = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id )->get_shop_name();
        
        // NOT in array
        if ( ! in_array( $shop_name, $shop_names ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $shop_names[] = $shop_name;

            // Output
            echo '<p>' . $shop_name . '</p>';
        }
        
    }
    
        // Empty array
    $store_phones = array();
    
        // Output
    echo '<h4>' . __( 'Seller Contact: ', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h4>';
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = $item->get_product();
        
        // Author id
        $author_id = $product->post->post_author;
        
        // Shopname
        $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id );
        
        $store_phone = $vendor->get_phone();
        
        // OR JUST USE THIS FOR SHOPNAME
        // Shop name
        // $store_phone = dokan()->vendor->get( $author_id )->get_store_phone();
        
        // NOT in array
        if ( ! in_array( $store_phone, $store_phones ) ) {
            // Push to array
            $store_phones[] = $store_phone;

            // Output
            echo '<p>' . $store_phone . '</p>';
        }
        
    }
}
```

Tested and works

[image]